# How to render data in ScrollView React Native (expo cli) from firebase realtime database?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, expo

I'm working on a ToDo app that is connected to the Firebase real-time database. Everything works fine. I can also store data in the Firebase database, but the problem is that I cannot get any data from the database. I want to render data in ScrollView so that the data can be displayed in ScrollView when I open my app.

**Main.js**

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import {
        StyleSheet,
        Text,
        View,
        TextInput,
        ScrollView,
        TouchableOpacity
    } from 'react-native';
    
    import Note from './Note';
    import firebase from './firebase';
    
    export default class Main extends React.Component {
    
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
    
            this.state = {
                noteArray: [],
                noteText: ''
            }
    
        }
    
        render() {

 let notes = () => {
    firebase.database().ref(`todos`).on('value', function (snapshot) {
      return <Note key={snapshot.val().key} keyval={snapshot.val().key} val={snapshot.val().note}
                    deleteMethod={() => this.deleteNote(key)}
                />
    });
  }
    
           
            return (
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <View style={styles.header}>
                        <Text style={styles.headerText}>Todo</Text>
                    </View>
    
                    <ScrollView style={styles.scrollContainer}>
                        {notes}
                    </ScrollView>
    
                    <View style={styles.footer}>
                        <TextInput
                            style={styles.textInput}
                            onChangeText={(noteText) => this.setState({ noteText })}
                            value={this.state.noteText}
                            placeholder='Enter Task'
                            placeholderTextColor='white'
                            underlineColorAndroid='transparent'>
                        </TextInput>
                    </View>
    
    
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.adTask.bind(this)} style={styles.addButton}>
                        <Text style={styles.addButtonText}>Add</Text>
    
                    </TouchableOpacity>
    
                </View>
    
            );
        }
    
        adTask() {
            if (this.state.noteText) {
                var date = new Date();
    
                var database = firebase.database().ref('todos');
                var key = database.push().key;
    
                var todo = {
                    'date': date.getDay() +
                        '/' + (date.getMonth() + 1) +
                        '/' + date.getFullYear(),
                    'note': this.state.noteText,
                    key: key
                }
                database.child(key).set(todo);
    
                this.setState({ noteArray: this.state.noteArray });
                this.setState({ noteText: this.state.noteText });
                this.setState({
                    noteText: this.state.noteText = ""
                })
            }
        }
```

**note.js**

```
     import React from 'react';
    import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
    import { AntDesign } from '@expo/vector-icons';
    
    export default class Main extends React.Component {
    
        render() {
            return (
                <View key={this.props.keyval} style={styles.note}>
                    <Text style={styles.noteText}>{this.props.val.note}</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.noteDate}>{this.props.val.date}</Text>
    
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.deleteMethod} style={styles.noteDelete}>
                        <Text style={styles.noteDeleteText}><AntDesign name="delete" size={24} color="black" /></Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
    
                </View>
    
            );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have delcared the noteArray state variable but you are not using it at all. Ideally you should setup a data change listener to `realtime database` and should update your local state when the data changes. You can setup a listener function and call it inside your `Main.js` file `componentDidMount` lifecycle method.

Inside this function, you can update your local state `noteArray` with the value received from the realtime database. You can then map over the noteArray to display your notes in your application with the help of a scrollview. I would personally suggest you to use the `FlatList` implementation of the react native in this use case, as this note array can grow over time. This will help you from the performace issues that you might face in the case of a long list and scrollview.

**Main.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput,
  ScrollView,
  TouchableOpacity,
  FlatList
} from 'react-native';
import Note from './Note';
import firebase from './firebase';

export default class Main extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      noteArray: [],
      noteText: ''
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.listenForNotes()
  }

  listenForNotes() {
    firebase.database().ref(`todos`).on('value', function (snapshot) {
      const notes = [];
      snapshot.forEach(child => {
        notes.push({
          note: child.val().name,
          date: child.val().date,
          key: child.key
        });
      });
      this.setState({
        noteArray: notes
      });
    });
  }

  adTask() {
    if (this.state.noteText) {
      var date = new Date();
      var database = firebase.database().ref('todos');
      var key = database.push().key;
      var todo = {
        'date': date.getDay() +
          '/' + (date.getMonth() + 1) +
          '/' + date.getFullYear(),
        'note': this.state.noteText,
        key: key
      }
      database.child(key).set(todo);
      this.setState({ noteText: "" });
    }
  }

  deleteNote(key) {
    // your delete note function
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.header}>
          <Text style={styles.headerText}>Todo</Text>
        </View>
        <FlatList
          data={noteArray}
          renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
            return (
              <Note
                key={item.key}
                note={item.note}
                date={item.date}
                deleteMethod={() => this.deleteNote(key)}
              />
            );
          }}
          key={(item) => `${item.key}`}
        />
        <View style={styles.footer}>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.textInput}
            onChangeText={(noteText) => this.setState({ noteText })}
            value={this.state.noteText}
            placeholder='Enter Task'
            placeholderTextColor='white'
            underlineColorAndroid='transparent'>
          </TextInput>
        </View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.adTask.bind(this)} style={styles.addButton}>
          <Text style={styles.addButtonText}>Add</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

You should also make some changes in the `Note.js` file to display the passed props.

**Note.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { AntDesign } from '@expo/vector-icons';

export default class Note extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const { note, date, key, deleteMethod } = this.props;
    return (
      <View key={key} style={styles.note}>
        <Text style={styles.noteText}>{note}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.noteDate}>{date}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={deleteMethod} style={styles.noteDelete}>
          <Text style={styles.noteDeleteText}><AntDesign name="delete" size={24} color="black" /></Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting error in FlatList component which is: ReferenceError: noteArray is not defined
        <FlatList
          data={noteArray}

when i change it to data={this.state.noteArray} it gives another error  which is: TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of null:

      this.setState({
        noteArray: notes
      });

Comment: what should i do now?

Comment: I have uploded my whole code here for testing please check: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-snowflake-1lddp?file=/src/App.js